# How to block a particular jabber_id to a particular person in ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

Hi i had installed ejabberd 16.04.43 in my server and its running as per as i needed.

Now i got new requirement to block a particular person to a particular user

Let me consider few users:

```
kandan
cash
mani
kumar
lokesh
```

Each of them has a particular jabber id in ejabberd and they interact with each other by using the command

```
add rosteritem
```

Now what i need is,

```
 **kandan blocks cash** such that any further message from kandan to cash or from cash to kandan should not deliver each other , so can anyone tell me how to implement?
```

i installed with mod_block , but am no where nearby to answer what i expected..!!!

Comment: You can use privacy_list to block users.

Comment: could you guide me please since am just a new born kid to ejabberd.

Comment: Check my answer. Replace example content with your actual content.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add user to a **privacy list** with action **deny**. And later if you wish to unblock then set the action to **allow**.

Example:

```
<iq from='romeo@example.net/orchard' type='set' id='msg1'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
  <list name='message-jid-example'>
    <item type='jid'
          value='tybalt@example.com'
          action='deny'
          order='3'>
      <message/>
    </item>
  </list>
</query>
</iq>
```

[documentation](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html#protocol-message).

Comment: How to call this using mod restful?

Comment: THis needs to be implemented from client side. So, say If A wants to block B then it should send from A to B. But if you still wish to use it from backend then u can use send_stanza method from mod_admin_extra.

Comment: Could you send me the syntax please ? ejabberdctl send_stanza kandan localhost

Comment: ejabberdctl send_stanza kandan localhost "<iq from='kandan1@localhost type='set' id='block1'>
  <block xmlns='urn:xmpp:blocking'>
    <item jid='karthick@localhost'/>
  </block>
</iq>"

Comment: what do u mean nothing worked out? Did u check the record in mnesia against the user? Btw I guess u have to use send_staza_c2s method.

Comment: am using sql database.

Answer (score 3):

For admin side you can send stanza using **send_stanza_c2s** command.

**Syntax**

ejabberdctl send_stanza_c2s Username Host Resourceid Stanza

**block stanza:**

```
<iq type='set' id='block123' from='user1@abc.com'>
     <block xmlns='urn:xmpp:blocking'>
        <item jid='user2@abc.com'>
        </item>
     </block>
</iq>
```

**Example**

```
ejabberdctl send_stanza_c2s user1 abc.com 69890942764773790857148098 "<iq type='set' id='block' from='user1@abc.com'><block xmlns='urn:xmpp:blocking'><item jid='user2@abc.com'></item></block></iq>"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot comment, but how will we get resource id. can't we do without resource id.

Comment: Yes, resource id is must following command using you can get resource id

ejabberdctl user_resources Username  Host